# html imessage pre-populate body

Tags: html, macos, sms, imessage

In my webapp, I have an html anchor that triggers iMessage on Mac using Safari, the use case is to populate the message's body and just have the user choose the recepient. The triggering works fine, but the body of the message actually appears in the To field:

```
<html>
    <a href="imessage://&body=THIS IS THE BODY OF A MESSAGE">
      THIS IS A LINK
    </a>
</html>
```

On the iphone this works:

```
<html>
    <a href="sms://&body=THIS IS THE BODY OF A MESSAGE">
      THIS IS A LINK
     </a>
</html>
```

I've tried several other separators other than ampersand like ; or ? but I can't get this to work on Mac OS. Any ideas?